# Android listView lost the data after scroll

Tags: android, listview

I have a problem with my listview!
When I change the row value (on the textview) and execute a scoll of the list, I lost the values (and return on my first setting)!
For example, if I create a listview with 50 textview with text = "Example no.1", if I change the value (onItemClick) after scroll list the textview value is "Example no.1".

This is my example code:

```
.............................................
String sItems = new String[50];
HashMap<String,Object> personMap=new HashMap<String, Object>();
.............................................
sItems[iCnt] = "Example no.1";
personMap.put("title", sItems[iCnt]);
data.add(personMap);
.............................................
String[] from={"title"};
int[] to={R.id.rowTextView};
final SimpleAdapter adapter=new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(),data,R.layout.all_textview,from,to);
final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cd_sel_title_listview_textview);
listView.setAdapter((adapter));

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id)
  {
    TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rowTextView);
    textView.setText("Example No.2");
  }
});
.............................................
```

Where i wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id)
{
TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rowTextView);

textView.setText("Example No.2");
personMap=new HashMap<String, Object>();
personMap.put("title", "Example No.2");
data.set(position,personMap);
}
```

Comment: @rostonik you're welcome. thank you too, you let me thinking of it for my projects

Answer (score 2):

The thing is : each view in your list won't be kept in memory for ever :

the adapter views allows you to have very long list, keeping in memory only the one you need to display, so when you scroll down,  and scroll back,  the view where the value changed where released  and recreated with its default values .

What you need to do is,  create a custom adapter (a class that extend from ArrayAdapter for example) and reimplement the `getView` method.

its the method where the view for each row is created ( or re-created). you can reset the text to its proper value at this point.

The code would look like :

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

...

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {

        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.myview, null);

    }

    v.setText("anything you need");

    return v;

}
```

Have a look at CustomAdapter implementations for more informations.

Comment: Is this the same issue when you scroll up and down in a listView, and only one list item will keep on changing. Only that one item will chnage; however, testing it via a new session might cause a different item to always change. I created a custom adapter from BaseAdapter. All my data is static, mock data. Just scrolling causes issues

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting value into TextView, change the values into Array itself and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to notify the adapter.

Comment: Far simpler than my solution, @rostonik you should try it first if it's enough for you ;)

Comment: @Paresh I am having problem with list view here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30850315/losing-images-from-networkimageview-after-scrolling-list-up-down