# Losing images from NetworkImageView after Scrolling list up-down

Tags: android, android-listview, android-volley, networkimageview

I have a **ListView** that grabs news with images associated with it using Volley Json. **At first** it loads everything but when i scroll the list and come back, it sometimes shows images and sometimes not. After scrolling 2-3 times `listview`
loses every image. Same procedure **works perfectly** with my **test app** (**With Actionbar Tabs Only**) so i don't know what is happening. Thanks in adavance for your time.

**Note:** I use `MySingleton` and `LruBitmapCache` from Developers site. My app's GUI is similar like Play Store i.e Navigation Drawer with Tabs. I searched problem like this but found no direct answer. Sorry if it is silly question to ask here.

**If** I use ViewHolder then that problem gets resolved but I am unable to remove NetworkImageView programmatically if URL is not there. 
**I don't** want to have placeholder image for row that doesn't have Image

Here is my layout file for row:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="8dp">

<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/cat_thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cat_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/cat_thumbnail"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cat_thumbnail"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cat_paper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/cat_title"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cat_thumbnail"
    android:textSize="15dip" />
```

**Adapter class**

```
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<NewsArticles> newsArticlesItems;
ImageLoader imageLoader;

public NewsAdapter(Activity activity, List<NewsArticles> newsArticlesItems)
{
    this.activity = activity;
    this.newsArticlesItems = newsArticlesItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return newsArticlesItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return newsArticlesItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int postion, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    if(inflater == null)
    {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cat_list_items, null);
    }
    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = MySingleton.getInstance(activity).getImageLoader();
    //Article image
    NetworkImageView thumbnail = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cat_thumbnail);

    //Article title
    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cat_title);

    //Newspaper Name
    TextView newspaperName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cat_paper);

    //


    if(!URLUtil.isValidUrl(newsArticlesItems.get(postion).getThumbnailUrl()))
    {
        thumbnail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    /*if(newsArticlesItems.get(postion).getThumbnailUrl()=="")
    {
        thumbnail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }*/
    else
    {
        thumbnail.setImageUrl(newsArticlesItems.get(postion).getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
    }

    title.setText(newsArticlesItems.get(postion).getTitle());
    newspaperName.setText(newsArticlesItems.get(postion).getNewspaperName());

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: `newsArticlesItems.get(postion).getThumbnailUrl()==""` -> `TextUtils.isEmpty(newsArticlesItems.get(postion).getThumbnailUrl())`

Comment: @njzk2 I am implementing your suggestion let you know

Comment: @njzk2 Still having problem with `NetworkImageView` after implementing your suggestion

Comment: @njzk2 Thank you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this in else block

```
else
    {
        thumbnail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//add this
        thumbnail.setImageUrl(newsArticlesItems.get(postion).getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
    }
```

Comment: here you are using convertView which is being reused, not getting inflated always.. may be in your test app you are inflating always

Comment: Does it work with ViewHolder? For smooth transition?

Comment: explanation: you probably have one or more invalid url in your list. Once that one is displayed, the image view is hidden, and propagated to other list items, because of recycling.

Comment: @njzk2 I used the If statement which is commented just below `if(UrlUtil)`.